# How to catch data from a drop down list to use it in SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, http-post

I've been trying to fix this code but I couldn't.

```
if ($_POST['number']) {
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $code = $_POST['code']; // I INSERTED THIS HERE TO GET THE DROPDOWN LIST VALUE
    //-connect  to the database  
    $db = mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die('cannot connect to the database  because: '.mysql_error());
    //-select  the database to use  
    $mydb = mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
    //-query  the database table  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM carmdi WHERE ActualNB LIKE '%".$number."%' AND CodeDesc LIKE '%".$code."%'";
    //-run  the query against the mysql query function  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

This is not the full code, but I inserted  `$code=$_POST['code'];` but it shows a white page, but when I use this instead `$code="g";`

It works fine, I don't know why it's not working from the dropdown menu.
can you help me please with this ?
thanks

Comment: whether the select box is having the name code and is it inside the form that u r posting

Comment: Have you got error reporting on?

Comment: you should check to ensure $_POST['code'] is being retrieved with isset()

Answer (score 1):

check if $_POST['code'] is set or not

Answer (score 1):

what does $_POST['code'] contains? tried to var_dump it?

by the way

```
 if ($number = $_POST['number'] && $code = $_POST['code']) {
```

looks much nicer ;)